# Remove "%" sign from Column in PowerBI table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a column (datatype = deciaml, format = percentage) in a table visual.
But it displays "%" along with value.

Is there any way to remove this sign but the value should remain as it is (should remain in decimal format) ?

Current : 2.55%

Expected : 2.55

Comment: You must multiply the value by 100. If you can't change the data, you can add a calculated column with the new value.

Comment: If I multiply value by 100, then it simply becomes 255%. I want to remove this % sign without while retaining actual value which is 2.55

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Got my answer. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Measure1 = 
ROUND(FORMAT(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Column]),BLANK())*100,2)
```

Ok. Just found my answer. This will remove the % sign.